# Display product detail using asp.net and sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, formview

I try to display product details from product table in my sql server database using querystring url, the url works fine and able to display the product id which user click such as ProductDetails.aspx?ID=1, ProductDetails.aspx?ID=2, etc.

But whatever the url passed, productdetails.aspx always show the first product id in my database.

I'm using listview to display product list, formview for display product details and ObjectDataSource to bind data from database.

```
<a href='ProductDetails.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
     <span><b><%# Eval("Judul") %></b>
     </span><br>
</a>
```

Comment: There should be code in your ProductDetails.aspx.cs's page_load event that handles the URL parsing. Can you post that?

Comment: I have this code in my page_load event Context.RewritePath(Path.GetFileName(Request.RawUrl));

Comment: Please update your question with that detail, but the problem is you arent doing anything with the query string value. Ideally you would be getting the ID from the query string, retrieving the records for that ID, then rebinding the grid/table.

Comment: please  update your question with page_load code

Comment: That is the code for generating the links. Please include the code from ProductDetails.aspx and/or ProductDetails.aspx.cs

Comment: As soon as I added the code for binding data in page_load event and make some modify in my objectDatasource method, it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering guys, at the beginning I don't have any clue how to solve this problem. As stingyJack suggest me to do following step to bind data for my formview and suddenly it works.

> 1. Change query using parameter "@ID" in method ProductDetailAccess.cs for Bind Data to ObjectDataSource

```
     namespace ProductDetail.App_Code
     {
         public class ProductDetail
         {
             public int ID { get; set; }
             public string Title { get; set; }
             public string Writer { get; set; }
             public int Publish { get; set; }
             public int Publisher_ID { get; set; }
             public int Category_ID { get; set; }
             public int Status_ID { get; set; }
             public string Book_Image_Url { get; set; }
             public int Jumlah { get; set; }
             public string Deskripsi { get; set; }
         }

         public class ProductDetailAccess
         {
             public static List<ProductDetail> GetAllProduct(int ID)
             {
                 List<ProductDetail> ProductList= new List<ProductDetail>();

                 string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs_productSample"].ConnectionString;
                 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                 {
                     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from T_Product where ID = @ID", con);
                     SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ID", ID);
                     cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                     con.Open();
                     SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                     while (rdr.Read())
                     {
                         ProductDetail ProductDetail = new ProductDetail();
                         ProductDetail.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
                         ProductDetail.Title = rdr["Title"].ToString();
                         ProductDetail.Writer = rdr["Writer"].ToString();
                         ProductDetail.Publish = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Publish"]);
                         ProductDetail.Publisher_ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID_Penerbit"]);
                         ProductDetail.Category_ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Category_ID"]);
                         ProductDetail.Status_ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Status_ID"]);
                         ProductDetail.Book_Image_Url = rdr["Book_Image_Url"].ToString();
                         ProductDetail.Jumlah = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Jumlah"]);
                         ProductDetail.Deskripsi = rdr["Deskripsi"].ToString();

                         ProductList.Add(ProductDetail);
                     }
                 }
                 return ProductList;
             }
         }
     }
```

> 2. I Add this code in Page_Load event

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string queryString = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        ObjectDataSourceDetailBuku.SelectParameters.Add("ID",queryString);
        ObjectDataSourceDetailBuku.DataBind();                
     }
```

Maybe there is another way to do this, please write your answer

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try using `<asp:Hyperlink>` server tag instead of `<a>` tag.
and use `Request.QueryString["ID"]` on the `PoductDetails.aspx` page to retrieve the value ProductID

Comment: For example :
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ProductID=@ProductID",con1);
SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID",Request.QueryString["ProductID"].ToString());

Comment: It was show the same result, but the Idea to put the parameter query work good